# How to add value to a Picklist field in a custom object?

Tags: apex, custom-object, picklist, insert

I want to insert a custom object and one of the field in the custom object is a `Picklist (Multi-Select)`. I used the following code:

```
PResources__c pResource = new PResources__c();
pResource.Name = title;
pResource.Description__c = description;
pResource.FileType__c = fileType;
pResource.Language__c = language;
pResource.ResourceUrl__c = resourceLink;
pResource.Category__c = selectedCategories;
pResource.UploadDateAndTime__c = DateTime.now();                                                
insert pResource;
```

In this code, the data type of `Category__c` is a `Picklist (Multi-Select)`. So, when I compile the code, this error shows up:

```
Illegal assignment from List<String> to String
```

`selectedCategories` is **String list**. When I comment this line: `pResource.Category__c = selectedCategories;`, the error is gone and insertion works fine. So, is there any other way to add data to a `Picklist (Multi-Select)` field?

Comment: Is this a multi-select picklist? Why are you trying to assign multiple values to a text field?

Comment: ya. its a multi-select picklist

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple type mismatch here. Like the error says, a `String` and a `List<String>` are different, and cannot be assigned to one another.

Picklist fields (including multi-picklists) are just strings (with some extra features) in the end.

You'll need to either:

- pick a single string from the list (e.g. `myStringList[1]`)
- turn the entire list into a single string using `String.join()` (e.g. `String.join(myStringList, ';')`)

Multipicklists have their values delimited by a semicolon `;`, and the second argument given to `String.join()` tells us which delimiter to place between each value in the list.

`String.join(new List<String>{'a', 'b', 'c'}, ';');` would return `'a;b;c'`

Comment: thank u for the answer. I am new to Salesforce. I thought that `Picklist` is a List type. So, if it is not a List, what is it?

Comment: @JayeshBabu Like I said in my answer, and like the error you're getting is indicating, it's a `String`.

Comment: k. Thank you for the clarification.